# Hibernate error for show is Transaction is active

Tags: java, hibernate

i have this code:

```
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
...
public void commitTransaction() throws PersistenceException {
    Transaction t = (Transaction) transaction.get();
    if (t == null) {
        throw new PersistenceException("Pas de transaction ouverte");
    } else if (!t.isActive()) {
        throw new PersistenceException("Transaction déjà fermée");
    }
    t.commit();
    transaction.set(null);
    closeSession();
}
```

but i have an error in this line:

```
...} else if (!t.isActive()) {...
```

Message error:

> The method isActive() is undefined for the type Transaction

i use `hibernate-core-5.0.7.Final.jar`

when i look in the `interface Transaction` there is not function `isActive()` why is present in old version of hibernate-core ..?

Answer (score -2):

It must have been refactored out. Since you are using new jar version you are not able to find it.You can try with this code -

if (TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive()) {
`enter code here`

}else{

is not active
}

Comment: `TransactionSynchronizationManager` is used for Spring ..??

Comment: I see you are looking for hibernate. You will have to use session object to query session.getTransaction().isActive().